# How to search for a certain keyword that match the variable in batch file

Tags: batch, csv

I have search and tried various question and solution that are posted in this site. But a beginner like me doesn't have the brain for it. The code below work well if I put 1 single string. how to change the search variable to find match value. I want it to work like: find *GXNM AD Service* in column 1 and print the output to a file. And can anyone explain it as well.

My CSV (input.csv):

```
Application,RequesterID,Date,VerifierID
"GX AD Service,""9900232"",""10/09/2014 17:51"",""9909142"""
"GX AD Service,""9900249"",""10/09/2014 17:51"",""9909142"""
"GXNT AD Service,""9900232"",""10/09/2014 17:51"",""9909142"""
"GXNT AD Service,""9900249"",""10/09/2014 17:51"",""9909142"""
"GXNM - Others - (Reset Staffs),""99001730"",""11/09/2014 9:00"",""99090615"""
```

My Batch Program:

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /p header=<input.csv
echo %header%>output2.csv

set column=1
set search=GXNM AD Service
cls

for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%A in (output.csv) do (
    set inline=%%A

    for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%1 in ("!inline!") do (
    set col1=%%1&set col2=%%2&set col3=%%3&set col4=%%$
    findstr /rx 
    if !col%column%! equ !search! echo !inline!>>output2.csv
  )
)

type output2.csv
set "cmd=findstr /R /N "^^" output2.csv | find /C ":""
for /f %%a in ('!cmd!') do set number=%%a
echo %number%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a pain to work with. You could use my [jgrep.bat](https://gist.github.com/krowe/da2a6b021ac891f8e3be) script for this.

```
@set @junk=1 /*
@echo off
cscript //nologo //E:jscript %0 %*
goto :eof
*/

args = WScript.Arguments
match = args(0);
if(match=="-t") match=args(1).replace("'", "\"");
var stdin = WScript.StdIn;
var stdout = WScript.StdOut;

// stdout.WriteLine("Arguments: "+match);

var regex = new RegExp(match);

while(!stdin.AtEndOfStream) {
    var sLine = stdin.ReadLine();
    if(regex.test(sLine)) stdout.WriteLine(sLine);
}
```

I'd consider this (mostly) self documenting but if you have a specific question about it then ask. Just put that file somewhere in your path and then run it like this:

```
cat input.csv|jgrep.bat "(AD Service|GXNM)"
```

This just uses a regular expression to match your lines. The expression means:

```
cat input.csv|jgrep.bat - Send the contents of input.csv to the jgrep.bat script.
(AD Service|GXNM) - Print only on lines which contain 'AD Service' or 'GXNM'.
```

It's that simple. Oh ya, if you'd rather have a header and save the results to a file, then it's still a one liner:

```
echo Application,RequesterID,Date,VerifierID>output.txt & cat input.csv|jgrep.bat "(AD Service|GXNM)">>output.txt
```